Where/how can I learn Telugu?
I want to learn Telugu. I have searched for resources and found almost nothing. Duolingo and most of the language apps don't have it. The few that do either have only very basic stuff (introductions and goodbyes) or give the audio so fast that I can't figure out how they are pronouncing things or be able to repeat it. I can't seem to find books and media or local groups either. I even went to the CIA's Foreign Language Learning site (whatever it was called - yes, it's publicly available!), but Telugu wasn't listed.
Does anyone know of any resources to help a total beginner learn Telugu?

Here's what you can do: go to this university site that has a Telegu language program and email one of the professors and ASK them if they can help you. By the way, I only looked in Andra Pradesh and only this uni. There are surely others in other states where Telegu is on the curriculum. https://cuap.ac.in/sot.html

That's the Central University of Andra Pradesh

Well, an acknowlegement would be nice.
